# How to change value dynamically in ngx-countdown-timer

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular4-forms

I'm using  ngx-countdown-timer but dynamically im not able to pass value please help me to do this.
is there any alternate solution for this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="swiper-slide desk" *ngFor="let i of dummy">
  <h1 style="margin-left: 17%; color:#df3b3b">
       <countdown-timer [end]="i.date"  class="dealbox"></countdown-timer>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check my code, it is working.
Component class dummy array;

```
     public dummy=[
        {
            'id':1,
            'date':'2019-06-01 00:00:00'
        },
        {
            'id':2,
            'date':'2019-07-01 00:00:00'
        }
      ];
```

Component html:

```
    <div class="swiper-slide desk" *ngFor="let i of dummy">
        <h1 style="margin-left: 17%; color:#df3b3b">
            <countdown-timer [end]="i.date"  class="dealbox"></countdown-timer>
        </h1>
    </div>
```